# Copying files from one connected USB drive to another connected USB drive while hard drive is full

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, filesystems

I'm using Windows.

I have two connected USB drives: USB #1 has 64 GB of data and USB #2 is empty.

My internal hard drive has no free disk space.

When I do a Copy on all the files in USB #1, and Paste them into USB #2, how is my computer able to do that despite my hard drive being full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don’t paste the files on the hard disk,
they don’t get written there.

When you “copy” files (in the sense of copy and paste), only the file names get written to the clipboard.

(I’m not sure where the clipboard is stored; as long as the contents are small enough, it’s probably in memory.)

Then, when you “paste” them onto the second USB drive, your computer copies them from the first USB drive.

(It reads the data from USB #1 into memory, and then writes it to USB #2, without using the hard disk.)

You can confirm this by ejecting USB #1 before doing the “paste” — the paste will fail.